# Dependency Injection in WPF on .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, mvvmcross, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement dependency injection and EF 6 in a WPF on .NET Core 6 project. Part of my code on `App.xaml.cs` is:

```
public partial class App : MvxApplication
{
    public static IHost? AppHost { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        AppHost = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
                services.AddSingleton<SuperheroContext>();
                services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
                services.AddSingleton<IMethodsBusinessLogic, MethodsBusinessLogic>();

                IConfiguration configuration;

                configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile(@"appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                services.AddDbContext<SuperheroContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
            })
            .Build();
    }

    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        await AppHost!.StartAsync();
        
        var startupForm = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        startupForm.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        await AppHost!.StopAsync();

        base.OnExit(e);
    }

    protected override void RegisterSetup()
    {
        this.RegisterSetupType<MvxWpfSetup<_App.App>>();
    }
}
```

I have a view model for navigation purposes and my goal is the CRUD operation.

So I have a `CreateViewModel`:

```
public class CreateHeroViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService navigator;

    public CreateHeroViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigator)
    {
        this.navigator = navigator;
        BackToNavigationManagerCommand = new 
        MvxCommand(BackToNavigationManager);
        CreateTheNewHeroCommand = new MvxCommand(CreateTheNewHero);
    }

    public ICommand BackToNavigationManagerCommand { get; set; }

    public void BackToNavigationManager() 
    {
        navigator.Navigate<NavigationManagerViewModel>();
    }

    public ICommand CreateTheNewHeroCommand { get; set; }

    public async void CreateTheNewHero() 
    {           
        //await methodsBusinessLogic.CreateHero(SuperheroModel);
    }

    private SuperheroModel _superheroModel = new SuperheroModel();

    public SuperheroModel SuperheroModel
    {
        get { return _superheroModel; }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref _superheroModel, value);
            RaiseAllPropertiesChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _heroName;
    private string _heroImage;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _location;
    private string _rank;
    private string _numberOfFriends;

    public string HeroName
    {
        get { return _heroName; }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref _heroName, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.HeroName);
        }
    }

    public string HeroImage
    {
        get { return _heroImage; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _heroImage, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.HeroImage);
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _firstName, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.FirstName);
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _lastName, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.LastName);
        }
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _location, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.Location);
        }
    }

    public string Rank
    {
        get { return _rank; }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref _rank, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.Rank);
        }
    }

    public string NumberOfFriends
    {
        get { return _numberOfFriends; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _numberOfFriends, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(SuperheroModel.NumberOfFriends);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I'm trying to inject to the constructor one of my configured services, for example the `SuperheroContext`.

I've searched to many places but couldn't find out why it's not working.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: When you say "the problem arises", I think you need to be a lot more specific.  What problem?  What is the symptom?  Are you able to build the code?  Does the constructor get called.  Do you get error output in the debugging?  Does an exception occur?  What happens when you debug?

Comment: If I try to use dependency injection to the Create View Model, when I try to Navihate to its View Model nothing happens,it doesn't navigate me with no errors. If I Try to Inject to the NavigationManager View Model the app crashes in the InitializeComponent() method of the MainWindowxaml.cs with this error:
   at SuperheroesWpfUI.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in 

MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter superheroContext of type SuperheroContext when creating SuperheroesWpfUI.ViewModels.NavigationManagerViewModel. You may pass it as an argument

Comment: Please update your question and add the complete exception message and all exception details (including stack trace of the exception and all possible inner exceptions) to your question.

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete, making it impossible to reproduce the problem. Worse, crucial parts of the code are missing making it impossible for anyone to see what the problem is. Please update the code sample and transform it into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are mixing two IoC containers here: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (IServiceCollection) and MvvmCross (Mvx.IoCProvider).

Comment: You are not seeing what's going on in the navigate methods because you are doing a few things wrong: 1) Don't use async void. 2) Use IMvxAsyncCommand when you have a command that needs to use async/await. 3) 'await' the IMvxNavigationService Tasks.